# IList<item> compare and check duplicate data

Tags: c#, winforms

After i get all the IList, i want to compare the card number, if that is same than return true, else return false.String card number is the text i get

the way i compare showing the error.

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'bool'

```
     public bool IsCardCodeDuplicate(long? organizationId, string cardNumber)
    {
        IList<CardDto> card = CardData.Instance.GetCardList(organizationId, null);

        //if (cardNumber != null)
        //{
        //    card = card.Where(p => p.CardNumber == cardNumber.ToString()).ToList();
        //    return true;
        //}

        if (card.Where(p => p.CardNumber == cardNumber.ToString())
            {
                return true;
            }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`card.Where(p => p.CardNumber == cardNumber.ToString()` returns a list of card with the specified Card Number. You can check the number of cards in the list by

```
var list = card.Where(p => p.CardNumber == cardNumber.ToString());
if (list.Count() > 0)
{
    return true;
}
```

Or better, try `card.Any(p => p.CardNumber == cardNumber)`, which returns a Boolean. `Any` has better performance because it will only yield the first matching element, while `Where` will yield all the matching elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool IsCardCodeDuplicate(long? organizationId, string cardNumber)
{
    IList<CardDto> card = CardData.Instance.GetCardList(organizationId, null);

    return card.Any(p => p.CardNumber == cardNumber);       
}
```

No need to convert `cardNumber` to string, since it is already string.